# Using AppleScript to convert XML to CSV, need help debugging

Tags: xml, csv, applescript, file-conversion

Somewhat redacted content from my input (XML) and output (CSV):

Input (this is the 9.8MB exported XML from LittleSecrets 1.9.4):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"      "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>LittleSecretsExportVersion</key>
    <string>1.9.4</string>
      <key>Secrets</key>
      <dict>
       <key>Children</key>
        <array>
          <dict>
            <key>Data</key>
            <data>
            cnRmZAAAAAADAAAAAgAAAAcAAABUWFQucnRmAQAAAC75
            BAAAKwAAAAEAAADxBAAAe1xydGYxXGFuc2lcYW5zaWNw
            ZzEyNTJcY29jb2FydGYxNjcxXGNvY29hc3VicnRmNjAw
            CntcZm9udHRibFxmMFxmc3dpc3NcZmNoYXJzZXQwIEhl
            -- ended here in this sample, this goes on
               for many lines and all children are below----
```

Output (this is the entire content of the resulting CSV file:

```
    key,string,key,dict
    LittleSecretsExportVersion,1.9.4,Secrets,missing value
```

I know there are other methods (using XSLT for example) but most are too far over my head as I am not a programmer, just (mostly) capable of following instructions. In my case, I think AppleScript (I'm a Mac user) is probably the easiest method for me, I just need help figuring out why a script I found isn't working.

I have an application from which I need to export all data to a new application, unfortunately the old app can only export in XML format, and all entries are encrypted (it's a very old password-storage application that must be transferred to a new password application). There are thousands of entries (because it stores more than just passwords) making manual transfer far too onerous.

While the new password application *can* accept .xml files as an import, it only accepts its own specifically formatted XML, so it won't actually process the file exported from the old program (it says "done" but no data is imported). It CAN also accept generic .csv files, so my task is to convert the encrypted XML file to a CSV file.

Since the data is confidential, I can't use an online converter. I did find an AppleScript that someone else wrote and posted here at this link, but it fails.

https://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=37025

Specifically this line is what Automater doesn't like:

```
write csvText to fRef as Â«class utf8Â»
```

I haven't been able to find enough information on how to write AppleScript to know what is wrong with that line... I could guess, but having no familiarity with AppleScript I don't think that's a good idea.

I found another completely different script here, but it also fails.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7178543?answerId=28761630022#28761630022

(this is also where I found the link above). This one just returns an error that says "Error: Operation in Progress" and creates a zero-byte file.

I would be deeply grateful for any help in either debugging what is causing these to fail, or in providing an AppleScript I can copy and paste into Automator that will work, or in suggesting a different method that is for non-programmers like myself.

Comment: That just looks like a formatting issue.  Those should just be the chevrons, e.g. `«class utf8»`.

Comment: That's pretty much what I thought based on my knowledge of HTML, but not knowing AppleScript I wasn't sure......I modified the script to remove the errant characters and now it *does* run without an error, but the resulting file has only one line (the first key) with a dict value that says "missing data" (so no children even though the XML file is almost 10MB of data).  I can only assume that the encrypted XML cannot be converted. :-( but thank you for your response, I do appreciate it.

Comment: You might edit your post to include a (redacted) sample of the input and output you are using.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I am sorry I didn't think of that earlier, but just updated to include what the input/output is....the input file is pretty large, and all of the dict values are very long strings of characters that are the encrypted data.....the old application (LittleSecrets) was (and is still) great for what it is, a place to store confidential information, but it simply isn't suited for syncing across devices or platforms and has no smartphone support.  It's just too old. Unfortunately it holds over 12 years worth of accumulated stuff.

Comment: The `data` elements aren't encrypted per se, the value is just encoded as [NSData](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata?language=objc) so the raw data would be legal in an XML/plist file.  There weren't any data elements in your referenced article, so there wasn't any decoding.  The data in your edit looks like it's from a Rich Text bundle (.rtfd), but there isn't much there except some formatting, or enough of the file to see the structure of the various entry types.

Comment: You can turn the property list into an AppleScript record that you might (or might not) find more enjoyable to parse: `tell application id "com.apple.SystemEvents" to return the value of property list file "~/path/to/your10MBfile"`.

Comment: Thank you @CJK but is that a complete AppleScript? Sorry for being such a n00b about this, I have no experience with AppleScript so I'm not sure how to actually implement your suggestion - does it replace one or both of the "tell" sections in the script I was trying to use (first link above at macscripter)?   There are a lot of examples of AppleScripts that I'm trying to learn from, just none that address this specific need.

Comment: I wouldn't learn too much from the AppleScripts you find online if you can avoid it, as most are badly written, a few are harmful, and even fewer are anything you would benefit from imitating (this includes macscripter, though actually **excludes** the one you linked to; you happened to find one by Stefan K who *is* a good one to learn from, and his script is solid, but simply not designed for your specific task). Stack Overflow is the best place for AppleScript, in my opinion. Ted Wigley, red_menace, user3439894, vadian and RobC are my recommendations to learn from. _Cont'd..._

Comment: _...Cont'd_ The line of code I provided actually does do a lot of a hard work that the macscripter script was forced to do manually. It reads in the XML property list file and returns to you a JSON-like data structure, with every piece of data associated to a key assigned to an AppleScript variable that resides inside a nested `record` object. You'll need to add a small amount of additional code to access the specific variables inside the record that are needed and print them out to a text file in CSV-style parroting.  It's a simple task, but a very tedious one, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thank you @CJK - that does make sense, even if I don't fully understand it yet.  I'll do my best to learn more about AppleScript so that I can do this task.....your input has been very helpful and appreciated!

Comment: That isn't intended as an implied refusal to help, by the way. But I and anyone else who would aim to provide a working solution would need to see more of the file than what's been shown. Those `NSData` values will comprise a big proportion of the file's 10MB, if they are cropping up regularly, which I suspect they will be. If you replaced the base 64 string between its `<data>` and </data>` enclosing tags, you'll be able to more easily share a more representative slice of the file. You also have to describe how you want to the CSV output (a 1-dimensional structure) to represent nested data.

Comment: Thank you @CJK, I didn't take it as a refusal to help, in fact you have been helpful. I've learned that I need to think this through more. I think a big part of the problem is that the data is in lots of folders and sub-folders, some a few levels deep - and here I thought I was being so organized all these years, :-)....now I see how that would be difficult to convert to CSV.  I think I need to 'flatten' it first, and remove older stuff and then it won't be so difficult.  For now I'm going to see if I can simplify this before moving forward again. I do deeply appreciate your input. :-)